# Pass record Id to an auto launched flow from an after delete trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, after-trigger

I have a requirement to update a field on a parent record after a child record is deleted. I would like to call an auto launch flow from an after delete trigger to handle the logic, however I'm having trouble passing the recordId from Apex into the flow. Does anyone have a good solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a record after it's been deleted. You'll need to use a before delete trigger with a DML statement. This should be allowed, but I don't have a way to test it right this moment.